# operator<< in template class; with namespace;

Tags: c++11, linker, mingw

I have a problem with linking the following piece of code. Linker could not find the implementation of friend template function.
Any idea why it could not find it?

Declaration

```
// XY.hpp
namespace xxx
{

template<typename T> class XY;

template<typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const XY<T>&);

template<typename T>
class XY
{
public:
    // ... constructors, destructor, getters, setters, etc
    friend      std::ostream& operator<< <T>(std::ostream&, const XY<T>&);

private:
    //...

};

} /* namespace xxx*/
```

Definition

```
// XY.cpp
#include "XY.hpp"

namespace xxx
{

template<typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const XY<T>& rhs)
{
    // ...
    return os;
}
} /* namespace xxx */
```

Usage

```
// main.cpp
#include "XY.hpp"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
using namespace xxx;

int main() {
    XY<uint16_t> xy;
    cout << xy;

    return 0;
}
```

Linker returns error: `undefined reference to 'std::ostream& xxx::operator<< <unsigned short>(std::ostream&, xxx::XY<unsigned short> const&)'`

Linking with `g++  -o "XXX"  ./src/XY.o ./src/main.o`
Version: `gcc.EXE (GCC) 6.3.0`

Comment: [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no operator<< definition when you define XY and use operator<<. You define a template in the source file, but there is no instantiation of this template for uint16_t. You can bypass via explicit template instantiation at the end of source file.

`template
std::ostream& operator<< <uint16_t> (std::ostream& os, const XY<uint16_t>& rhs);`

But I think this is not a good idea. You'd better declare and define template in header file.